# Apple Maps directions is not working on iPhone with iOS15

Tags: iphone, maps

When I want to get directions on any place in my iPhone with iOS15, I get this message "Directions not available. It's very anoying because I cannot use the apple map.

PD: I'm in Paraguay, the picture is just a example but is the same error. I'm using WIFI and Cellular Data.

In Apple maps I can see the blue dot but not the Directions.

Google Maps and Waze both work very well

[image: Example of the issue]

Comment: Does this happen all the time? only indoors? only outdoors? Are you using Wi-Fi or cellular? More information is needed to find a solution.

Comment: Do you see a blue dot for your location? Does google maps work?

Comment: In which country are you? Does Apple Maps even offer directions there? Can you get directions to get from London to Edinburgh for instance?

Comment: I'm in Paraguay, the picture is just a example but is the same error. I'm using WIFI and Cellular Data.

In Apple maps I can see the blue dot but not the Directions.

Google Maps and Waze both work very well